# Replaced toggle button with a checkbox but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I replaced the button on the jQuery toggle code with a checkbox but cannot get it to work.

Here is the HTML file where I tried to replace the button with a checkbox

**index.html**

```
<p> hi </p>
<!--<button>Press me</button>-->
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {

    if (Cookies) {
        $("p").toggle(!( !! Cookies("toggle-state")) || Cookies("toggle-state") === 'true');
    }

    // $('button').on('click', function()
    $('#myonoffswitch.onoffswitch').is(":checked"), function() 
     {
        $("p").toggle();
        Cookies.set("toggle-state", $("p").is(':visible'), {
            expires: 1,
            path: '/'
        });
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d32j1tyt/)

What is wrong here?

Comment: But, what do you want the Ouput to be ? You wrote question, but what are expecting in answer?

Comment: @AlivetoDie, the <button> on the Html and the $('button').on('click', function() on the script is commented out. these were the original code and I am trying to get it work with a checkbox.

Comment: @DeepakYadav, hide and show on toggle

Comment: @Mecom - In `$('#myonoffswitch.onoffswitch')` the class `onoffswitch` **does not exist**. The class used on that element is `onoffswitch-checkbox`. So the function would not even be called. The `onoffswitch` is used on its parent instead but not on that element

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa, I tried what you said but not working. Can you show me on the Fiddle I posted?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are not working with check-box class at all. that's why it's not working.

Do it like below:-

Change-

```
$('#myonoffswitch.onoffswitch').is(":checked"), function() {
```

To

```
$('.onoffswitch-checkbox').click(function() {
```

And everything will work fine.

Working example:- https://jsfiddle.net/2uz0rsq8/

Note:- you can use :- `$('.onoffswitch-checkbox').change(function(){`  also (by @NikhilNanjappa)

Comment: @Mecom glad to help you:):)

Comment: Just to add on you can also use `$('.onoffswitch-checkbox').change(function(){`

Comment: @AlivetoDie - `change` event. Just another option to the OP

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa  good one.Added to answer.Thanks. Missed while seeing

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(function() {
 

      $('#myonoffswitch').click(function(){
              /*Use toggle if you need only hide and show */
              //$("p").toggle(); 
              
              /*If you want to know the current status of checkbox       go with below code*/
          if($(this).is(':checked')){
                  $("p").show();
          }else{
                  $("p").hide();
          }
      })
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> hi </p>
<!--<button>Press me</button>-->
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>
</div>
```

```
  $('#myonoffswitch.onoffswitch').is(":checked"), function() 
     {
        $("p").toggle();
        Cookies.set("toggle-state", $("p").is(':visible'), {
            expires: 1,
            path: '/'
        });
    });
```

change this code to

```
       $('#myonoffswitch').click(function(){
          /*Use toggle if you need only hide and show */
          //$("p").toggle(); 

          /*If you want to know the current status of checkbox   go with below code*/
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
              $("p").show();
      }else{
              $("p").hide();
      }
  })
```

Comment: I replaced the whole script but it does not toggle.

Comment: @Mecom check the snippet if you are looking for this